# Making an AST constructor for a compiler, can't figure out segfault

Tags: c, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree, bison

So I'm currently making a c-- compiler for a school project (due today) and I have a segfault that I can't figure out. There is a considerable amount of code don't want to overwhelm this question with all of it.

I ran GDB and it pointed out a couple of functions of one file, but I couldn't tell what the issue is, probably because I don't have that much experience with C. The functions are being called from another file.

Bellow are the used functions/structures of the file, GDB pointed to the lines I commented. I can tell it can't access the parent of a node, but I can't figure a reason for that.

I'm watching this post, if you feel some code or info is missing please point out and I will edit the post instantly.

PS: AST is a node. All this code is C.

```
#define CHILDREN_LIMIT 20
struct node {
    NodeKind kind;
    int data;
    int count;
    AST* parent;
    AST* child[CHILDREN_LIMIT];
};

AST* new_node(NodeKind kind, int data) {
    AST* node = malloc(sizeof * node);
    node->kind = kind;
    node->data = data;
    node->count = 0;
    node->parent = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < CHILDREN_LIMIT; i++) {
        node->child[i] = NULL;
    }
    return node;
}

void add_child(AST *parent, AST *child) {
    if (parent->count == CHILDREN_LIMIT) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot add another child!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    parent->child[parent->count] = child;
    parent->count++;
    child->parent = parent; // GDB POINTS HERE
}

AST* get_child(AST *parent, int idx) {
    return parent->child[idx];
}

// Adds s2 as child of s1 parent
void add_sibling(AST *s1, AST *s2) {
  if (s1->parent->count == CHILDREN_LIMIT) { // GDB POINTS HERE
      fprintf(stderr, "Cannot add another child!\n");
      exit(1);
  }
  s1->parent->child[s1->parent->count] = s2;
  s1->parent->count++;
  s2->parent = s1->parent;
}

AST* new_subtree(NodeKind kind, int child_count, ...) {
    if (child_count > CHILDREN_LIMIT) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Too many children as arguments!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    AST* node = new_node(kind, 0);
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, child_count);
    for (int i = 0; i < child_count; i++) {
        add_child(node, va_arg(ap, AST*));
    }
    va_end(ap);
    return node;
}
```

----------EDIT------------------

On my parser (bison) these are the caller rules and it's derivates:

```
write-call: WRITE LPAREN STRING RPAREN { new_subtree(WRITE_NODE,1,$3); }; // THIS ONE

var-decl-list: var-decl-list var-decl { add_sibling($1,$2); $$ = $1; } // AND THIS ONE
| var-decl { $$ = new_node(VAR_LIST_NODE, 0); add_child($$,$1); };

var-decl: INT ID SEMI { var_size = 0; $$ = new_var(); }
| INT ID LBRACK NUM { var_size = atoi(yytext); $$ = new_var(); } RBRACK SEMI;

AST* new_var() {
    int index = lookup_var(vt, current_id, scope);
    if (index != -1) {
        printf("SEMANTIC ERROR (%d): variable '%s' already declared at line %d.\n",
                yylineno, current_id, get_var_line(vt, index));
        exit(1);
    }
    index = add_var(vt, current_id, yylineno, scope, var_size);
    AST *vd = new_node(VAR_DECL_NODE,index);
    if(var_size > 0) {
      add_child(vd,new_node(NUM_NODE,var_size));
    }
    return vd;
}
```

On my scanner (flex) I also have:

```
{number} { yylval = new_node(NUM_NODE, atoi(yytext)); return NUM; }
{string} { int index = add_literal(lt, yytext); yylval = new_node(STR_NODE, index); return STRING; }
```

Comment: Edited the question. The compiler is for C-- but all the code is C.

Comment: I double checked and my allocation is correct. Can you explain what you mean by the setting child node with unknown values?

Comment: We will need to see the callers of `add_sibling` and `new_subtree`.

Comment: Updated with callers.

Comment: Ah yes, I get what you are doing with `* node`.  My mistake.  As torek said, without knowing the callers, it's not possible to be sure of certain types of error (e.g. local variables that go out of scope etc.).

Comment: It's a lot easier to build ASTs without parent links. Why do you think you need them? Anyway, there are various problems with your code. One problem you could have avoided if you had read [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56620571/1566221) more carefully. (Hint: what does `$$` mean in a MRA?). Another problem is probably `current_id`; I don't know where you are setting it, but I'm guessing it's in your lexer, in which case it is not going to be in synch with your parse, leading to obscure bugs with certain inputs. You should use the semantic value, not a global, to communicate...

Comment: But to get back to AST parents, you call `add_sibling` in an action for `var-decl-list`. Afaics `add_sibling` assumes that its first argument already has a parent. I claim that `$1` at that point doesn't yet have a parent. But of course I can only see a bit of your code. Prove me wrong, if you can. Or fix it.

Comment: Finally, I don't know what you mean when you say that "gdb points at" those two lines. What do you mean by that? I don't see how those two lines can be in the same backtrace, if that's what you meant. Are you talking about two different backtraces from two different inputs? What are the inputs? Please read the advice on preparing a [mre], emphasis on "minimal".

Comment: Hello again @rici thank you for all your help. I thought in using parent links because I needed to create nodes (from rules) that have an indefinite nº of children and are recursive e.g. the block nodes seen on this tree https://pasteboard.co/IkeRldh.png

Comment: I see what you mean by $1 not having a parent at that point and I guess you are right, I think this must be my main issue. Thought bison handled parsing differently. But I can't seem to think of another way to do it. Do you have some idea on how to fix it?

Comment: Simple solution: parent has pointer to first child; every node has pointer to next sibling. That's a standard tree representation, which shows the isomorphism between general trees and binary trees.

Comment: And yes those where two different backtraces. The inputs are simple C-- programs. And yes sorry about the scattered info, I had little time to spend on this project and the due was 2 hours ago. Total panic time when I posted this.

Comment: That's a really nice simple solution, should have thought on this before making parent links, definitely will do. Thanks again @rici :)

Comment: Since you're rushing, I'll just leave you with the other part: bison parsers (usually) construct lists left-to-right which means each new node has to go on the end. But it's way easier to construct a linked list by adding each new node at the beginning. If you do that, the list ends up being backwards. Fortunately it's really easy to reverse a list in place, which you need to do when you finally make the list the child of some node (`$$.first_child = reverse($2);` or code to that effect).

Comment: Note that `reverse` must return the head of the reversed list, which will be the tail of the argument, which will, in fact, be the first element pushed onto an empty list. An empty list can just be a `NULL` pointer. Good luck!

Comment: Add more warning options to your compiler command line.  Compile with `-g` for debug info. Use `valgrind` on your program before debugging with `gdb`; it finds problems that lead up to a crash, rather than just the crash itself.